# Use Angular2 component on a specific page only

Tags: laravel-5.1, angular

I have to two pages served by laravel 5

localhost/**home**

localhost/**login**

In my home page, i have an angular2 component called `<my-app></my-app>` and is working fine.

But when i visit the login page which doesn't contain any component, angular throws me an error **"EXCEPTION: The selector "my-app" did not match any elements"**. How do i fix this issue when visiting the login page.

I did all the bootstrapping for Angular 2.0 Beta in my master layout page which makes the bootstrapping available to both pages.

Comment: If you copy and pasted the component from /home for the login check your selector property make sure you changed it.

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template:`
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    `
})

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for the solution for a few hours. A solution that works for me is in main.ts:

```
if (document.querySelector("homeSelector")) {
    platform.bootstrapModule(HomeModule);
}
```

Similarly for other pages and other modules.

Answer (score 0):

It means you declared a Component with the `my-app` selector but you are not using the `<my-app>` anywhere.

Comment: Yes. i am only using the selector on the home page only.

Comment: that's why your home page works and your login page doesn't

Comment: bootstrap just one entry point AppComponent declare the my-app in there, and from that component handle the /login and /home pages.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realized  the single entry.

Answer (score 0):

Angular2 requires at least one component if you start the app. A workaround could be something like the following.

```
if(window.location.pathname == '/home') {
   bootstrap(myapp); // or your initialization
}
```